# Security and getting a certificate: designing a protocol

Tags: ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate, tls1.2

In the beginning of an SSL query, the client sends a CLIENT_HELLO message.
The server replies with a certificate message that gives the chain of verifications going back to a known trusted agent.

Suppose for efficiency I wanted to store certificates locally for a new protocol. The current design in TLS is always to require getting the certificate.  What could happen to a certificate that would require me to know?

I am trying to understand possible attack scenarios.  Consider doing online banking, and suppose a certificate has been compromised.  In such as case, the bank is not criminal, but they have been hacked and have to issue a new certificate.  Is this reasonable?

If you consider that the bank itself is corrupt, then it seems to me there is no point in worrying about the certificate since they have your money and can just steal it.  If the entity you are dealing with goes criminal, does the certificate matter?

Under what circumstances can certfiicates be revoked?  I am trying to understand why SSL sends the certificate each time -- it seems really wasteful, but there is probably a good reason.

Would it be possible instead to keep all certificates stored on the client, but check a timestamp with a trusted server?  It seems like one could at least send less data across the network

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLS `Certificate` message after `ServerHello is mandatory in mostly cases, so caching won't have any useful effect. See [RFC5246](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5246.txt)

> **7.4.2.  Server Certificate**
>
> When this message will be sent:
>
> **The server MUST send a Certificate message whenever the agreed- upon key exchange method uses certificates for authentication**  (this includes all key exchange methods defined in this document except DH_anon).  This message will always immediately follow the ServerHello message.

TLS has its own methods to improve performance. When client sends a valid `session_id` in `ClientHello` the session can be resumed and  the parties must proceed directly to the Finished messages

Also [RFC5077](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5077)   specifies how to resume sessions without server-side state

EDITED - added comments to specific questions

> Suppose for efficiency I wanted to store certificates locally for a new protocol. The current design in TLS is always to require getting the certificate. What could happen to a certificate that would require me to know?

"always" is not correct. TLS sends certificates during handshake. Once the shared key is negotiated, the session can be resumed later by client using `sessionid` (the usual behaviour). Then, the server does not send the certification chain.

The server sends the certification chain. The client must verify that the presented certificate is reliable:

- **checking a digital signature** performed with the private key of the server certificat
- **the certificate is issued by a trusted CA**. Is supposed that client has a trust store with the root certificates of the certification authorities it trust. The client builds the certification chain presented by server until it finds the root certificate in local truststore

You can perfectly skip the sending of certificates from the server in the second step step if client has a copy of the server certificate in a local truststore

> I am trying to understand possible attack scenarios. Consider doing online banking, and suppose a certificate has been compromised. In such as case, the bank is not criminal, but they have been hacked and have to issue a new certificate. Is this reasonable?

In this scenario the attacker could make a MITM attack. The certificate must be revoked by CA and client should check revocation. This is out of scope of TLS

> If you consider that the bank itself is corrupt, then it seems to me there is no point in worrying about the certificate since they have your money and can just steal it. If the entity you are dealing with goes criminal, does the certificate matter?

Seems in this case the certificate is the least of the problems...

> Under what circumstances can certfiicates be revoked?

Each CA stablish its own procedure. There is no a standard but there are "good practices": When certificate data changes (e.g email) or becomes invalid (Representative of a company), after a renewal revoke the older one, when key is compromised or certificate is lost

> Would it be possible instead to keep all certificates stored on the client, but check a timestamp with a trusted server?

Yes it is possible as commented above: Verify a digital signature, verify revocation and stablish a refreshing mechanism

But if you're looking for performance comparing with TLS, the session resumption will probably have better results

Comment: Thank you for this useful information about TLS, but is this necessary for security, or just a feature of TLS.  Suppose I propose to change the protocol to make certificates load once and reload upon request.  Is there a security problem with that?

Comment: This is a TLS requirement. If you know the certificate that the server is using then it would not be necessary to send it, because the authenticity is proven with a digital signature made with the private key of the certificate. You could check it using your local copy

Comment: I rephrased the question to make my intent clearer.  I am asking, not about TLS, but about security in general, and WHY TLS does it that way.

Comment: I answered your specific questions, trying to focus on why certificates are sent in TLS but you can apply the same concept to other systems using digital signatures when client has to verify trust